# While loop only delivering first sql row

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

Source code is showing 16 items as requested by LIMIT. However all are only the first item in the column 'category'. How can i get this to show the first 16 rows of the column, not just the first one.

```
<div id="contentContainer" class="trans3d">
  <?php include("../scripts/db.php");
    $query="SELECT category FROM stories LIMIT 16"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  ?>
     <section id="carouselContainer" class="trans3d">
  <?php   
      while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            $genre=$data['category'];
            $genre_path=$genre.".php"; 
            $genre_img_path="../images/genre_images/".$genre.".jpg";
  ?>

<a href="$genre_path">
    <figure class="carouselItem trans3d">
        <?php echo $genre;?>
            <img src="<?php echo $genre_img_path;?>" alt=""/>
    </figure>
</a>
<?php 
     endwhile;
     mysqli_close($connection);
 ?>
        </section>

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Maybe the first 16 stories in the table all have the same category.

Comment: bu they don't, is LIMIT random? It's interesting also it picks a category called "adventure" which is NOT the first row in my table but would be the first "category" by alpha-numeric

Comment: try `SELECT DISTINCT`, also as a side note rows are not guaranteed to be returned in any particular order

Comment: maybe i'm wrong... but is the syntax for `while` right? Shouldn't it be `while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { /*More code*/}` (That `:` is not familiar to me)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works @serakfalcon   never even heard of it before. thank you all

Comment: @Barranka `while(): endwhile;` is an alternate acceptable syntax.

Comment: @Barranka PHP has two syntaxes for all the block constructs. You can either surround the body with braces or precede it with `:` and use an `endXXX` keyword.

Comment: What is that : making. SQL code is flawless. if your table's first 16 row are not same. it will work. This must be php with a creepy while algo.

Comment: serakfalcon & Barmar :O I didn't know that! Thank you!

Comment: @Barranka no I've seen it both ways and have never been able to determine a difference between the two. good observation

Comment: endwhile;. wow. most sickest close brackets since the if ... fi of bash script

Comment: @user2102266 It comes from Algol and Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the query to:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM stories LIMIT 16";
```

This will ensure that you get 16 different categories. Otherwise, the selection of which 16 rows is arbitrary, and it might pick 16 stories that happen to be in the same category.

Comment: @buzrw does your table contains same category values in first 16 rows? or do you get same result?

Comment: @user2102266 It doesn't it's different values in the first 16. Without the DISTINCT added it does deliver the first one via alpha numeric

Comment: What you think the "first 16" are may be different from how they're saved in the database. Records in a table are not in any particular order that's controlled by the user, you need to use `ORDER BY` to specify the ordering of results.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to get 16 different categories (with no duplicate), you should use the keyword `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM stories LIMIT 16
```

If you want the `category` from the 16 first lines in the table `stories` (possibly with duplicates), then your request is correct.

If the issue is that you do not get the category you're expecting, maybe try to ensure the correct ordering of the firstly selected rows with an `ORDER BY` clause.